# What happens when the docker host restarts?

Tags: docker

What happens when the docker host is shut down and restarted?

- will the images that were running be restarted?
- will the changes that were made to those images persist, or will a new instance of the image be spawned and changes be lost?
- does docker have any configuration option, such as the list of images to be automatically executed at startup and the options to run the images? Where? If not, I suppose only the docker command line can be used to alter docker state. Where is that state stored (I suppose somewhere in `/var`). This could be useful to backup the docker state.

(I'd have liked to find this in the [FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/faq/))

Comment: I think it should work if it wasn't for this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18797089/174011

Comment: See also https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/

Comment: See also: http://blog.sogilis.com/post/94520400771/how-to-deploy-services-using-docker

Answer (score 30):

> will the images that were running be restarted?

Docker will restart containers when the daemon restarts if you pass `-r=True` to the startup options. On Ubuntu, you can accomplish this permanently by modifying `DOCKER_OPTS="-r=true"` in `/etc/default/docker`.

> will the changes that were made to those images persist, or will a new instance of the image be spawned and changes be lost?

Containers will be stopped. Any modifications to the container will still be present when the container next starts, which will happen automatically when the docker daemon starts if `-r=true` is provided as mentioned above.

> where is the docker configuration stored on the host system?

There is no configuration file per se. You can tune the upstart/init options in `/etc/default/docker`.

Comment: I was not talking about the init system configuration for docker but the docker configuration in itself. I modified the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The `--restart` or `-r` option is indeed what I was interested in. It is now the default according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18797089/174011

Comment: Obvious but important comment: if the container is run with --rm, then the container will be stopped and automatically be removed, so all changes will be lost