# Docker Container is disappeard after restart service

Tags: docker, splunk

I stopped my docker container.
and i restart the service in linux (service docker restart)

after that my container is missing.
I typed `docker ps -a` but I can't find my splunk container.

I can find container directory and volume folder also.
also I have every folder in inspection result.
but I can't see when I type `docker ps -a`

how can I restore it ?

this is my docker inspect result, when container is exist.

```
    [
    {
        "Id": "9e12bb7b2f8a926c0b7852aa9f1bf957363f327d6de53778059bf0fc05711039",
        "Created": "2018-10-02T04:05:28.013507313Z",
        "Path": "/sbin/entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "start-service"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 11513,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-09-22T05:22:09.939497539Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2020-09-22T05:20:05.99542747Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:507021d7e77f9bdd337aeb47729a806162579f36e5d73b14f2a508e545adae72",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/storage/docker/containers/9e12bb7b2f8a926c0b7852aa9f1bf957363f327d6de53778059bf0fc05711039/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/storage/docker/containers/9e12bb7b2f8a926c0b7852aa9f1bf957363f327d6de53778059bf0fc05711039/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/storage/docker/containers/9e12bb7b2f8a926c0b7852aa9f1bf957363f327d6de53778059bf0fc05711039/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/storage/docker/containers/9e12bb7b2f8a926c0b7852aa9f1bf957363f327d6de53778059bf0fc05711039/9e12bb7b2f8a926c0b7852aa9f1bf957363f327d6de53778059bf0fc05711039-json.log",
        "Name": "/splunk",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8000"
                    }
                ],
                "8089/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8089"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/storage/docker/overlay/25444b7c23c5d0bf0a6d4d1563a587831b7c329e6623ee720e609a0a16787ef5/root",
                "MergedDir": "/storage/docker/overlay/53d6023089444b76af280ef1220a2851c1b5045167c471f5f60f9faa0389ccd3/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/storage/docker/overlay/53d6023089444b76af280ef1220a2851c1b5045167c471f5f60f9faa0389ccd3/upper",
                "WorkDir": "/storage/docker/overlay/53d6023089444b76af280ef1220a2851c1b5045167c471f5f60f9faa0389ccd3/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "cb9d0886db87a17304310bfa5a242972bf9c76464eb0c85c24902c7764443714",
                "Source": "/storage/docker/volumes/cb9d0886db87a17304310bfa5a242972bf9c76464eb0c85c24902c7764443714/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/splunk/etc",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "5d637a70101b4d6a80261abfeac9534b8b77bde4669c6225dedf3a9bcfb4434a",
                "Source": "/storage/docker/volumes/5d637a70101b4d6a80261abfeac9534b8b77bde4669c6225dedf3a9bcfb4434a/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/splunk/var",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "9e12bb7b2f8a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "1514/tcp": {},
                "8000/tcp": {},
                "8088/tcp": {},
                "8089/tcp": {},
                "8191/tcp": {},
                "9997/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license",
                "SPLUNK_USER=root",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "SPLUNK_PRODUCT=splunk",
                "SPLUNK_VERSION=7.0.0",
                "SPLUNK_BUILD=c8a78efdd40f",
                "SPLUNK_FILENAME=splunk-7.0.0-c8a78efdd40f-Linux-x86_64.tgz",
                "SPLUNK_HOME=/opt/splunk",
                "SPLUNK_APPS=/opt/splunk/etc/apps",
                "SPLUNK_GROUP=splunk",
                "SPLUNK_BACKUP_DEFAULT_ETC=/var/opt/splunk",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "start-service"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "klustree/splunk:7.0.0",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/splunk/etc": {},
                "/opt/splunk/var": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/splunk",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "57cf9a7d9ec5d31e685fd5ea9232a3126fab1a90406449cc4d48b43a2f7c4f57",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "1514/tcp": null,
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8000"
                    }
                ],
                "8088/tcp": null,
                "8089/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8089"
                    }
                ],
                "8191/tcp": null,
                "9997/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/57cf9a7d9ec5",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "b4d39d4b6615127cd6aaeda1e0e14e73d910fadf9b596d5b81698d3fc1c53945",
            "Gateway": "172.17.1.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.1.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 24,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:01:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "c563f5e5d0e2e4bd6d35f5802395f77874679e40a522dabaee59b93d3747619c",
                    "EndpointID": "b4d39d4b6615127cd6aaeda1e0e14e73d910fadf9b596d5b81698d3fc1c53945",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.1.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.1.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:01:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

please help...

Comment: These links may help. Basically, it seems like you have to start your container with a special flag to tell the host that you always need the container running, even if the docker service restarts. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753561/what-happens-when-the-docker-host-restarts

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of the docker service, in the docs we learn:

> By default, when the Docker daemon terminates, it shuts down running containers. Starting with Docker Engine 1.12, you can configure the daemon so that containers remain running if the daemon becomes unavailable. This functionality is called live restore. The live restore option helps reduce container downtime due to daemon crashes, planned outages, or upgrades.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#enable-live-restore) you can learn how to keep your containers alive when occurring a service timeout.

And [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) you can configure for your containers still alive when the docker service is restarted.

Although live-restore and the restart policy might seem similar they have different purposes:

> Restart policies are different from the --live-restore flag of the dockerd command. Using --live-restore allows you to keep your containers running during a Docker upgrade, though networking and user input are interrupted.